# showing Wordpress category description

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to display the Wordpress category description and name separately (two different locations) What is the code to just display the description and not the category name or slug?

currently using

```
 <h2><?php the_category('  |  '); ?></h2>
```

to display just the name of the category

EDIT

This is a Wordpress custom theme site, and adding the simple

```
 <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>
```

generates nothing for me. It may be because I need to add something in my functions.php (which is probably a better and more specific way to have asked my question) the html I am using it in

each 'article' is a post

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-12'); ?>>

 <div class="bg-img-L" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>');">

<!-- Put cat div overtop article -->
<div class="cat-cell">
    <div class="cat-border">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h2><?php the_category('  |  '); ?></h2>  
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- / bg-img-L -->  

</article>
```

Comment: You do realize this place is for problems that can't be solved "just like that"? **I got your answer with first Google search in less than 5 seconds.**

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a built-in function for that since 1.0.

```
 <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>
```

The full function reference is available at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

One tip I would give you for the future is look at the bottom of the function reference pages. These will have links to other related functions that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: First time using Wordpress really, I can't believe I missed that description. Didn't think it was as easy as that since other similar thing take more code

Comment: No problem. Those function references can be a bit esoteric to read at points. But we all started out as novices when it came to WordPress so I can definitely relate.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>
```

[LINK](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description) < Found your answer in 5 seconds, even typing question to stackoverflow wasn't worth your time nor lazyness.

**Just like that!**